# Excel VBA code works only when Outlook is visible

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
MsgBox (OutApp Is Nothing)

On Error GoTo errorHandler
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        'OutMail.Parent.Display '****
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .Body = "Body"
            .Se
        End With
        On Error GoTo errorHandler
        Set OutMail = Nothing
```

If I want the email to be sent, I have to uncomment the `OutMail.Parent.Display` line. Why should I annoy the user like that by making outlook visible?  Is this a security setting or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not necessary :) Also I guess `.Se` is a typo in the code mentioned in the question?

This works for me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = cell.Value
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .Body = "Body"

        .Send '<~~ .Display to display
    End With

LetsContinue:
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```